# How can I apply apply filter to 3 different Colums of a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I have to apply filter to column J,F and AE of a worksheet, but when I ran the code all the filters are deselecting.

Here is my Code:

```
Worksheet("sheet").Range("J:J").AutoFilter _
      Field:=1,
      Critical1:="Fruits",_
      VisibleDropDown:=True, 
Worksheet("sheet").Range("F:F").AutoFilter _
      Field:=1,
      Critical1:="Doll",_
      VisibleDropDown:=True,
```

Comment: You have to use the same range for it to have effect.

Comment: Also, if you paste a screenshot of your Data, that would be helpful in answering.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Worksheet("sheet").Range("F:J").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Fruits", VisibleDropDown:=True
Worksheet("sheet").Range("F:J").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Doll", VisibleDropDown:=True
```